# Find perticular value from mongodb collection

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

I am writing **Python3** code to get values from **MongoDB**.
I have one collection which has only 2 records.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c35b8aa04f44540cbea189d"), "BTCBlockNumber" : 1708 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c3711d47095538174d342b6"), "ETHBlockNumber" : 1 }
```

Now I want to find only value by passing key name. Like If pass BTCBlockNumber to function it should return only 1708 but not whole record.
I am trying following code:

```
class gogo():

    def __init__(self):
        myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://ipaddress:port")
        targetdb = myclient["TestDB06"]
        self.col = targetdb["CheckMissedBlockNumber"]
    def MongoCheckNumber(self,item):
        getcheckblocknumber = self.col.find({},{item:1}) 
        print(list(getcheckblocknumber))

x= gogo() 
x.MongoCheckNumber("ETHBlockNumber")
```

It's not giving expected output.
Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

**Follow these below Code:**

```
getcheckblocknumber = self.col.find({},{item:1, _id: 0})
```